# How to get read write access of one drive of a linux server from another linux server

Tags: linux, mount

I have created one partition in linux server x.x.x.23 named /common. Now I want the drive from linux machines x.x.x.24 and x.x.x.25 with all the privilege. The /common drive will be available in both 24 and 25 servers like /common. Is there any way to do that? I am using CentOS 6.3 (64bit) and Dell Server.
-Amit

Comment: Check for nfs or sshfs.

Answer (score 1):

- Activate NFS if not running on all servers
- Edit `/etc/exports` of x.x.x.23 and add IP addresses of x.x.x.24 , x.x.x.25
- Finally mount this partition from x.x.x.24 , x.x.x.35

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Samba](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/165) and map the drive on the network.
or you could use [SSHFS](http://www.spencerstirling.com/computergeek/lufs.html).